# Firebase Auth Not Working With Ktor App On AppEngine

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-firestore, ktor

## Issue

When deploying a **Ktor** Kotlin application to AppEngine per the [Ktor tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-ktor-app-engine-java8), the Firestore server authentication is not working, thus data is not being written to the specified Firestore database.

Data is written as expected to Firestore both when the app is run directly in the IntelliJ IDE as well as when it is run with **ktor**'s implementation via the `gradle appengineRun` command.

There are two sets of AppEngine/Firebase projects for both a *staging* and *production* environment. Prior to deploying with the `gradle appengineDeploy` command the correct SDK configuration been activated and verified via the command `gcloud config configurations list.`

[image]

The strange part is that a few of the apps deployed with these strategies did write to Firestore, however upon deploying the app again Firestore did not show new data being written to it.

## Implementation

### Ktor Setup

I have the standard **ktor** required files. I also have an old *MANIFEST.MF* file from an older implementation. Could that be causing issues?

*src/main/resources/application.conf*

```
ktor {
  application {
  modules = [ Initialization.main ]
  }
}
```

*src/main/resources/webapp/WEB-INF/*

*appengine-web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<servlet>
    <display-name>KtorServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>KtorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.ktor.server.servlet.ServletApplicationEngine</servlet-class>
    <!-- path to application.conf file, required -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>io.ktor.config</param-name>
        <param-value>application.conf</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>KtorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

*logging.properties*

`.level = INFO`

*src/main/META-INF/MANIFEST>MF*

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Initialization
```

### Dependencies

For authentication strategies outlined below **#1-3** the Firebase Admin library is used: `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.5.0'`

For authentication strategy **#4** the Google Cloud Firestore library is used: `compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.58.0-beta'`

**build.gradle**

```
group 'coinverse'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.61'
    ext.junitJupiterVersion  = '5.0.3'
    ext.ktor_version = '0.9.4'
    ext.appengine_version = '1.9.60'
    ext.appengine_plugin_version = '1.3.4'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
    classpath "com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:$appengine_plugin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = [ 'src/main/kotlin' ]
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
mavenCentral()
jcenter()
maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
        testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")
        testCompile("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.10.0")
        testCompileOnly('org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0')
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
        compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'
        compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.58.0-beta'
        // Or compile 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-firestore:0.58.0-beta'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.5.0'
        compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
        compile "io.ktor:ktor-server-servlet:$ktor_version"
        compile "io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version"
        providedCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine:$appengine_version"
}

kotlin.experimental.coroutines = 'enable'

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

task run(dependsOn: appengineRun)

appengine {
    deploy {
        version = 'price-staging-1021653pm'
        stopPreviousVersion = false
    }
}
```

### Initializing Firebase Strategies

**1. [Initialize on Google Cloud Platform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize)**

This method is promising as credentials are managed automatically.

```
// Use the application default credentials
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault();
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(credentials)
    .setProjectId(projectId)
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
```

**2. [Initialize on your own server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize)**

I've confirmed in GCPs *IAM & admin* > *Service accounts* that the key id's match with the Json object being used to authenticate.

I'm using this strategy successfully in another Firestore connected app deployed to AppEngine. The working app is built as a **.Jar** and deployed directly to AppEngine without using **ktor**, but rather with the steps outlined [here](https://medium.com/r/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fhackernoon.com%2Fdeploy-a-backend-app-as-an-android-engineer-49bd94b4c367).

```
// Use a service account
InputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("path/to/serviceAccount.json");
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount);
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
    .setCredentials(credentials)
    .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);

Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
```

In my working **.Jar** built app I'm passing in the **Json** object programmatically to avoid issues with the file not being found. I tried the same programmatic implementation for this **ktor** application. It worked with `gradle appengineRun` but not when deployed.

```
val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(Gson().toJson(FirebaseCredentials(
            "service_account",
            "project-name",
            "asdfghjkl",
            "keyStringHere",
            "firebase-adminsdk-dhr30@project-name.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
            "1234567890",
            "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
            "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
           "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-dhr30%40project-name-staging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    )).byteInputStream())
    val options = FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://project-name-staging.firebaseio.com")
            .build()

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options)
```

**3. Initialize on your own server (Firebase console setup)**

The only difference between **#2** is this setup adds `.setDatabaseUrl("https://yourProjectName.firebaseio.com")`.

[image]

**4. [Initialize cloud Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers)**

```
FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions =
FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
    .setProjectId(projectId)
    .build();
Firestore db = firestoreOptions.getService();
```

### Accessing Firestore Object

For **#1-3** the Firebase app is initialized right away in the application's **main()** method. Then, the **Firestore** object is accessed from an object.

**FirebaseClient.Kt**

```
object FirebaseClient {
    val firestore: Firestore
    init {
        firestore = FirestoreClient.getFirestore()
    }
}
```

For **#4** the Firestore object is created in the Kotlin object's `init{...}` and stored in the object as a value.

**FirebaseClient.Kt**

```
object FirebaseClient {
    val firestore: Firestore

    init {
        val firestoreOptions = FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
            .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
            .setProjectId("project-name")
            .build()
        firestore = firestoreOptions.service
    }
}
```

### Writing to Firestore

`FirebaseClient.firestore.collection(someCollection).document(someDocument).collection(anotherCollection).add(someObject)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After utilizing Firebase authentication for a different project I discovered this is not an issue with Firebase authentication but rather with the application's **main** method. Therefore the various implementations above of Firebase authentication will work as expected when deployed to AppEngine.

## Solution

I was expecting the application's **main** method to run once the app is deployed to AppEngine, similar to how an application's main method is called when ran in IntelliJ. However I realized **main** is only called once the app's hosted route is called.

ie: `https://[yourProjectName].appspot.com`

I've created a new *StackOverflow* post in order to determine [how to run a Ktor app's **main** method automatically once deployed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53575270/ktor-apps-main-method-not-called-when-deployed-to-appengine).