# Ktor App's Main Method Not Called When Deployed to AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, kotlin, ktor

## Issue

The Ktor application's **main** method is not called when deployed to AppEngine. In the applications's main method is logic to retrieve content from an API request based on a **Timer** and save that information to a Firestore database which a client consumes.

This logic currently works when deployed in a *Jar* to AppEngine. However, implementing this with *Ktor* would save deploy time and help future proof the backend service if endpoints are required.

## Expected

The Ktor application's **main** method is called once the app is deployed to AppEngine similar to how an application's main method is called when ran in IntelliJ.

## Actual

The **main** method is only called once the app's hosted route is called.

ie: `https://[yourProjectName].appspot.com`

## Setup

*Main Method*

```
import io.ktor.application.Application
fun Application.main() {
    // App logic here.
}
```

*build.gradle*

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.10'
ext.ktor_version = '1.0.0'
ext.appengine_version = '1.9.60'
ext.appengine_plugin_version = '1.3.4'
ext.junitJupiterVersion  = '5.0.3'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:$appengine_plugin_version"
    classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.3'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.2.51'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs = [ 'src/main/kotlin' ]
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor" }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-server-servlet:$ktor_version"
    implementation "io.ktor:ktor-html-builder:$ktor_version"
    providedCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine:$appengine_version"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev204-1.23.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    // JUnit Jupiter API and TestEngine implementation
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitJupiterVersion}")
    testCompile("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.10.0")
    // To avoid compiler warnings about @API annotations in JUnit code
    testCompileOnly('org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0')
}

kotlin.experimental.coroutines = 'enable'

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

task run(dependsOn: appengineRun)

appengine {
    deploy {
    version = 'media-staging-1201181257pm'
    }
}
```

*src/main/resources/application.conf*

```
ktor {
    application {
        modules = [ InitializationKt.main ]
    }
}
```

*src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/*

*appengine-web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <runtime>java8</runtime>
</appengine-web-app>
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <servlet>
        <display-name>KtorServlet</display-name>
        <servlet-name>KtorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>io.ktor.server.servlet.ServletApplicationEngine</servlet-class>
        <!-- path to application.conf file, required -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>io.ktor.config</param-name>
            <param-value>application.conf</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>KtorServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you to Gabriel Machado on [Kotlin Slack](https://surveys.jetbrains.com/s3/kotlin-slack-sign-up) for answering this.

Gabriel recommends using a [**Cron Job**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron-yaml) as opposed to a **Timer Task** because there may be issues with a **Timer** thread based on [scaling type](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/how-instances-are-managed).

Comment: Follow up question, [How to Run Cron Jobs in Kotlin Ktor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59516599/how-to-run-cron-jobs-in-kotlin-ktor)

Answer (score 0):

GAE probably expects your app to look like a Java app (e.g., a Java style "main", not a Kotlin style "main").
Look at this for more info on how to do this: [How to run Kotlin class from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733566/how-to-run-kotlin-class-from-the-command-line)