# How to Run Cron Jobs in Kotlin Ktor?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, kotlin, google-cloud-functions, ktor

**Is there a way to run Cron Jobs with [Ktor](https://ktor.io/)? My end objective is to host a Cron Job written with Kotlin for the [Coinverse app's](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.coinverse) backend service to populate data.**

I'm currently hosting multiple Java *.jar* apps written in Kotlin on AppEngine. I'm looking to refactor these apps into Ktor apps on AppEngine with a [Cron Job](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron-yaml) for scheduled tasks, as the *.jar* apps have more issues with dependencies.

I'm looking for Ktor's equivalent to Cloud Functions' [built-in implementation](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/04/schedule-cloud-functions-firebase-cron.html) for Cron Jobs with JavaScript.

```
functions.pubsub.schedule
```

*Back-up option:* If Ktor does not have this feature and I want to keep the code in Kotlin, Google has an alpha, [Using Kotlin with Google Cloud Functions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kotlin-samples/tree/master/functions). It appears Kotlin + Cloud Functions' built-in implementation could be used with this approach.

Answer (score 7):

Sergey Mashkov from the JetBrains team suggests in the [kotlinlang](http://slack.kotlinlang.org/) Slack group to launch a Kotlin `Coroutine` on the `Application` scope using an infinite loop and [`delay`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/delay.html).

Then, the *Ktor* app can be [deployed](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/kotlin-ktor-app-engine-java8#deploy_your_application) to AppEngine.

```
fun Application.main() {
    launch {
        while(true) {
            delay(600000)
            // Populate data here.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As for my experience, this will not work the app will stop after 20 minutes or so.
The only solution I've found is to make a regular cron.yaml and and a ktor app, and it works without complain....(the ktor app shall implement a get, and will be called by the cron file)

Comment: Interesting approach, thank you! It seems like the ktor app would be constantly running with this approach which might be more expensive than required.